# System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

Tags: c#, group-policy

I am collecting Resultant Set of Policies using the Group Policy Management dll. There exist a class [GPRSop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmi_v2/class-library/gprsop-class-microsoft-grouppolicy), which I use, with the attributes RsopMode and WMI Namspace as a string:

```
GPRsop test = new GPRsop(RsopMode.Logging, "Root/RSOP");
test.LoggingMode = LoggingMode.Computer;
test.LoggingComputer = "MyComputer";
test.LoggingUser = "domain\\user";
test.CreateQueryResults();
test.GenerateReportToFile(ReportType.Xml, "C:\\Temp\\test.xml");
```

`LoggingMode`, `LoggingComputer` and `LoggingUser` all throw the same exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

If I set the wmiNamespace " " as recommended, it also throws an exception.

Comment: maybe this helps: [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4049095/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-error-when-you-change)

Comment: Is CreateQueryResults getting any results?  I think the error is occurring because the GenerateReportToFile() is failing do to result being empty.   I would put an exception handler try/catch and get the trace stack to get more info on error.

Comment: @jdweng GenerateReportToFile() runs successfully if CreateQueryResults() is not used. But then the report does not contain any information.

Comment: @jdweng Here the stack trace:

   at Microsoft.GroupPolicy.GPMRSOPClass.set_LoggingFlags(Int32 lVal)
   at Readinizer.Backend.Business.Services.ADRSoPService.getRSoP() in C:\Users\lkellenb\Documents\Readinizer\Readinizer.Backend.Business\Services\ADRSoPService.cs:line 33
   at Readinizer.Frontend.ViewModels.StartUpViewModel.<Discover>b__25_0() in C:\Users\lkellenb\Documents\Readinizer\Readinizer.Frontend\ViewModels\StartUpViewModel.cs:line 64
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Comment: See example of parameters.  Note that all parameters have backslashes and you are using a forward slash : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/get-gpresultantsetofpolicy?view=win10-ps

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem was solved by running Visual Studio as an Administrator. After that i did not need to provide a wmiNamespace.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run Visual Studio as an administrator. After that I did not even need to provide a wmiNamespace.

Thanks for your help